# How can I make the logo on mobile appear on the left side but keep it in the center on large screen?

Tags: html, css

I built this navbar using vanilla CSS and Flexbox and I like how it behaves on large screen. The logo is in the center which is okay on desktop.

I would like the logo to be on the left on mobile. In other words I want to keep the logo in the center on desktop and on the left on mobile, like so:

[image]

My version positions the logo on center on mobile which is not what I want:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #921801;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: top 0.3s linear 0s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 57px;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hamburger, .hamburger::before, .hamburger::after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger::before, .hamburger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.hamburger::before {
  top: -8px;
}
.hamburger::after {
  top: 8px;
}

.menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #921801;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu li + li {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.nav-menu li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-dropdown {
    position: initial;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: initial;
  }

  .logo {
    margin: 25px 0 5px;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-menu li > a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav-menu li + li {
    border-top: initial;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="header.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">

      <!-- Site logo -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div> <!-- / .logo -->
      
      <!-- Site navigation -->
      <nav class="nav">
        <div class="menu-toggle">
          <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div> <!-- / .menu-toggle -->

        <div class="menu-dropdown">
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- / .menu-dropdown -->
      </nav>

    </div> <!-- / .header-container -->

  </header>

  <script src="header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd have to make use of a css media query to target mobile devices and write a different set of rules for those devices.

Comment: Insert this rule: `.header-container { width: 100%; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; }`

Comment: I use a mobile first approach, so the media query is for desktop which works fine. If I use what you wrote outside the media query it works on mobile indeed, but now it messed up my desktop which shows it on the left as well. I want it on the left only on mobile.

Comment: I checked my own code in your snippet. Works well for me, and does not break the desktop version of the template. I have put my code outside of the media query.

Comment: It works indeed. Thank you. I removed the `align-items: center;` accidentaly that was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for starters `margin: 0 auto; display: flex;` contradict each other since there is no set width, as it will shrink to minimum and flex cannot do its job. So `.header-container` should look something like this:

```
.header-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As for logo on mobile, this will be the job of media query:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

And now all together

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #921801;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: top 0.3s linear 0s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 999999px) {
  .logo{ align-self: flex-start; }
}

.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 57px;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hamburger, .hamburger::before, .hamburger::after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger::before, .hamburger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.hamburger::before {
  top: -8px;
}
.hamburger::after {
  top: 8px;
}

.menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #921801;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu li + li {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.nav-menu li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-dropdown {
    position: initial;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: initial;
  }

  .logo {
    margin: 25px 0 5px;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-menu li > a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav-menu li + li {
    border-top: initial;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="header.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">

      <!-- Site logo -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div> <!-- / .logo -->
      
      <!-- Site navigation -->
      <nav class="nav">
        <div class="menu-toggle">
          <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div> <!-- / .menu-toggle -->

        <div class="menu-dropdown">
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- / .menu-dropdown -->
      </nav>

    </div> <!-- / .header-container -->

  </header>

  <script src="header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You code does not work on desktop. By "does not work" I mean it puts the logo on the left as well. I want that only on mobile.
BTW I used the mobile first approach. So everything outside the media query is mobile, the media query I used is for desktop only. Let's not inverse it because it causes only confusion.

Comment: You can flip it to become mobile-first. As for desktop, change query dimensions.